# How to get the current Site (group) for the connected user on the post login hook Liferay DXP 7.0 in order to get the Site CustomField

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-theme

I am using `Liferay DXP 7.0` and I am trying to get the current Site of the connected user to do some specific instructions on the `login.events.post` hook.
I have tried:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
themeDisplay.getSiteGroup().getExpandoBridge()
                .getAttribute("mySiteCustomField");
```

But `themeDisplay` is returning null.

Thank you in advance.

best regards,
Chaimaa

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the *HttpServletRequest* from the lifecycleEvent and then from the request you can retrieve the *VIRTUAL_HOST_LAYOUT_SET*, there you can get the group ID.

```
HttpServletRequest request = lifecycleEvent.getRequest();
LayoutSet layoutSet = (LayoutSet)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.VIRTUAL_HOST_LAYOUT_SET);
layoutSet.getGroupId();
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your response.
Actually, I have applied what you suggested above and it is also getting a null : LayoutSet layoutSet = (LayoutSet)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.VIRTUAL_HOST_LAYOUT_SET);
Do you have please any other suggestions?

Thank you for your support.
Chaimaa.